# Tips on playing arpeggios fast ([eg. c arpeggio] c, e, g, (now octave higher) c, e, g)

Tags: piano, technique

I have trouble making the c major arpeggio sound smooth. Whenever I attempt to play it smooth, it sounds like groups of 3, perhaps because I press each note too hard.

What are some tips on playing the c major arpeggio?

Comment: By 'C chord run' do you mean 'arpeggio'? And do you mean the 4th note played (C) is too emphasised?

Comment: Yes, "apreggio" that is what it is called! Now, when I seach for it on google I actually get some desired results, as opposed to when I searched for chord runs.

Yeah, my issue is that the 4th note is too emphasised, how do I practice "smoothening the notes out"

Answer (score 1):

You found a solution, not, maybe, the solution.Can't really see what his elbow is doing, but it could be nudging to the right on the way up, in order to get that thumb underneath the palm ready for the next C.

I prefer students to move the whole hand during and after playing the G with middle finger,, so the thumb is ready to play the next note, C. His method is more like leave the hand where it is on C E and G until it has to move, and then put the thumb under, so it reaches the next C. Mine is keep the hand (and arm) moving all the time, so it sort of slides over the keys, dropping on notes as the fingers are over them. Elbow doesn't have to move at all, except in line with the wrist, instead of out in a nudging action. Much easier to explain in a video - which I don't have - but somewhat different from your guy's approach. Give it a few tries and let me know!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are crossing your thumb under the palm and uncurling it is hindering timing?  Maybe you are twisting your wrist in ulnar deviation which will create an uneven sound.

Try this: Don't abduct (stretch out) your fingers but instead, as you ascend move your arm up the keyboard so that the arm places the hand and next finger. Also, since your fingers are all different lengths when executing a 123 1235 fingering play on the outer edge of the key where they are lightest, then come out for the index, out further for the middle, all while raising the forearm a bit, then repeat with an in motion for the thumb.  Of course, in for the pinky at the end.

There are other movements such as rotation (using the pronator and supinator around the elbow) and forward shifting into the keys but start with the aforementioned.

Here is a $175 lesson:

Answer (score 0):

- Relax your wrist and arm and relieve all tension.
- Make sure everything you're doing feels natural. If it's uncomfortable, don't do it or try to do it as little as possible.
- Remember to go across the keys with minimal effort as if you're laying a blanket rather than trying to dig into every note.
- If you relax into the keys, your arm weight will automatically do the hard work for you.
- Having correct playing posture helps - keep your wrists elevated, playing with your fingertips, etc.
- This might seem obvious but check your fingering.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with all of the above comments, but there's another simple way to figure out what's going wrong (and also to improve the speed and fluidity) - slow down! I've found that the best way to figure out what's going wrong is to slow down the arpeggio (or scale, or whatever) until I can get it perfectly smooth... and then speed it up slowly  (time after time after time) until it's second nature to play it smoothly and quickly. Another great tip? Changing up the rhythm - pick a noticeable rhythm (a bell, cartoon sound, or whatever) - and then play the arpeggio to the rhythm of that. It forces you to think and feel more carefully whatever's coming next, rather than "next note/next note/next note".

Answer (score -1):

Act naturally.

There are always rigid teacher with rigid methods and teaching the only single way, as “don’t turn your wrist, don’t move your elbow, don’t stretch your fingers, don’t tap your feet.”

Why not combining all natural movements: a little help by  the  under going thumb, a slight turn of the wrist, a quick move of the hand, a slight support by the elbow all in a coordinated natural movement.